# How to find the total of prerequisites in a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I have the following graph nodes:

[image]

These nodes represent skills of a character in a video game. The 0<sup>th</sup> node is the base skill that all characters start with. The 1<sup>st</sup> node is a skill that requires the 0<sup>th</sup> node as a prerequisite. Likewise, the 2<sup>nd</sup> node requires the 1<sup>st</sup> node as a skill, which requires the 0<sup>th</sup> node as a skill. However, when a skill is learned, it does not need to be re-learned.

I am given an array T, which is `[0,0,1,1]` and an array A, which is `[2]`.  The K<sup>th</sup> skill can be learned only if the T[k]<sup>th</sup> skill has already been learned. 0 is root, so it is learned without needing any other skill. The above array is explained like this: `T[0] = 0`, `T[1]=0`, `T[2]=1`, `T[3]=1`, hence `T=[0,0,1,1]`. Array A tells me the skill(s) that I want to learn. My output needs to be the total number of skills I'd need to learn to learn skill 2. In the above example, the answer is `3`

### Example 2

[image]

In the 2<sup>nd</sup> graph, the answer is 5 because I am asked to learn 2,5,6 so I would be learning 0, 2, 3, 5, and 6. My inputs are these: `T=[0,0,0,0,2,3,3]` and `A = [2,5,6]`

I've been thinking about how to solve this. It's a coding exercise to improve my graph theory. But I don't know how to correlate between the T list and the A list algorithmically.

### Example 3

[image]

In the above example `T = [0,3,0,0,5,0,5]` and `A = [4,2,6,1,0]`.
I created `X = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` to map T to its connections.

What do I know?

- 0 is already always learned so `count = 1`
- Learning 4.

  To learn 4, I have to learn 5, so that makes me learn 0 (which is learned). count = 1 + 2 = 3
- Learning 2.

  To learn 2, I have to learn 0. count = 3 + 1 = 4
- Learning 6.

  To learn 6, I have to learn 5 (already learned), which makes me learn 0 (already learned). count = 4 + 1 = 5
- Learning 1.

  To learn 1, I have to learn 3, which makes me learn 0 (already learned).
  count = 5 + 2 = 7

So I have to return this count, which is 7

### My Code

So far this is what I have:

```
def sol(T,A):
    count = 1
    x = [i for i in range(len(T))]

    if 0 in A:
       A.remove(0)

    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        indx = x.index(A[i])
        if T[indx]==0:
           count += 1
           break
        else:
           # nothing yet
```

Comment: in 2nd example you won't be learning 0 as its default you said, but how `T=[0,0,0,0,2,3,3]` ? What value at `T[i]` denotes ?

Comment: @Vimal check my edit. I am explaining the logic.

Comment: This is a recursion problem. I figured out the logic. I just don't know how to implement it in code.

Comment: Look into graph search algorithms. Specifically you want to find the shortest paths (you want an algorithm that will give the actual path not just the distance) to all the skills you need to learn noting the nodes you come across along the way. That provides all the skills you need to learn. Remove duplicates if any and remove the base node and you should have what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nuclearman said in a comment, you want to find the shortest paths to all the skills you need to learn.

What you also need to know is that this is a standard problem in graph theory, which is most efficiently solved using Dijkstra's algorithm. You can find numerous descriptions of this algorithm and sample code implementing it.

But why re-invent the wheel?  Any graph library will provide a well tested and efficient implementation.  I use boost graph.

The algorithm:

```
read input
Run Dijsktra
loop over required skills
   loop over path to required skill (from Dijsktra run )
       if not skill already learned
           record new skill
display skills learnt
```

I use the [PathFinder C++ wrapper](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder) for the boost graph library

The input

```
t 0 0 0 0 2 3 3
a 2 5 6
```

The output

```
skill 2 needs 0 2
skill 5 needs 0 2 5
skill 6 needs 0 3 6
Total skills needed 5 ( 0 2 3 5 6  )
```

input for example 3

```
t 0 3 0 0 5 0 5
a 4 2 6 1 0
```

output

```
skill 4 needs 0 5 4
skill 2 needs 0 2
skill 6 needs 0 5 6
skill 1 needs 0 3 1
Total skills needed 7 ( 1 3 2 0 4 5 6  )
```

The code

```
void doPreReqs()
{
    cPathFinder finder,
    cPathFinderReader reader( finder );
    std::set<int> setSkillsNeeded;

    // read input. va are the required skills
    auto va = reader.singleParentTree();

    // starting node
    finder.start("0");

    // paths to all end nodes
    finder.end(-1);

    // run Dijsktra
    finder.path();

    // loop over required skills
    for (auto &a : va)
    {
        // skill 0 does not need to be learned
        if( a == "0" )
            continue;

        //skills needed to get required skill
        auto path = finder.pathPick(finder.find(a));

        std::cout << "skill " << a << " needs ";
        for (int s : path)
            std::cout << finder.nodeName(s) << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";

        //loop over prerequsites
        for (auto s : path)
        {
            //record skill if not already learned
            setSkillsNeeded.insert(s);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Total skills needed "
              << setSkillsNeeded.size() << " ( ";
    for (int s : setSkillsNeeded)
        std::cout << finder.nodeName(s) << " ";
    std::cout << " )\n";
}
```

I have added this as an option in the graphical user interface to pathfinder.  [Documentation](https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use recursion as implementation of a depth-first traversal (a breadth-first traversal would also work). Use a `set` to keep track of the nodes you have already visited. For larger inputs this will be more efficient that calling `index`.

Here is a recursive algorithm. Note that I have used `itertools` to combine multiple results into one. There are many other ways to do that as well:

```
import itertools

def sol(tree, needed):
    visited = set()

    def dfs(node):
        if node in visited:
            return []
        visited.add(node)
        return dfs(tree[node]) + [node] if node else [0]

    return list(itertools.chain(*map(dfs, needed)))
```

This will output the skills that need to be learned, so you would just need to take the length of it, to get the desired answer. However, it may be useful to get this list: it is also returned in an order in which you could learn those skills, always starting with 0, and ensuring that the prerequisites are fulfilled when you stick with the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.deque` with an iterative approach:

```
from collections import deque
def earn_skill(T, A):
   a, r = deque(A), [0]
   while a:
      if not T[(n:=a.popleft())] or any(j in r for j in T[:n]):
         r.extend([T[n], n])
      else:
         return
   return len(set(r))

vals = [([0,0,1,1], [2]), ([0,0,0,0,2,3,3], [2,5,6]), ([0,3,0,0,5,0,5], [4,2,6,1,0])]
r = [earn_skill(t, a) for t, a in vals]
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 7]
```