# Graph theory, topological sorting, how to modify DFS to check "corequisites"

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, topological-sort

Say each node in my graph represents a college course, how can I use DFS to check what's a corequisite of course X and what's a prerequisite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the total of prerequisites in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646335/how-to-find-the-total-of-prerequisites-in-a-graph)

Comment: What is a "corequisite"?